# How to import product images in bulk into Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-images, migration

I'm moving my store from ver 1.7.2 to 2.0.2.

Since I have less than 200 products I will export/import them using CSV files, however I'd like to know how to import product images.

Comment: > You can use a different folder on the Magento server, as long as the
> path to the folder is specified during the import process. I'm trying to do so but did not find the correct way. I want to sort my files myself. All files start with TO100.2240.png TO120.6255.png and so on. So I want to put them in folders TO100/ TO120/ when I now import into magento2 magento plces the files in /t/0/ folder. So all files are in the same folder 4000+ images. like: pub/media/catalog/labels/to100 files start to100
pub/media/catalog/labels/to120 files start to120 wat is the exact pad then?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146277)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magento 2 uses the same folder structure for product images. Assuming your CSV contains the product image attribute, you can simply copy `/media/catalog/` to `/pub/media/catalog/`

Comment: Not enough. At least not in Magento 2.1.5. You must copy the whole /media/catalog/product/ to /pub/media/import and then run de CSV list import. Don't forget to specify the path for importing images: /pub/media/import

Answer (score 18):

> #### Method 1: Import Images from the Local Server
>
> 1. On the Magento server, upload the image files to the `pub/media/import` folder. This is the default folder for importing product images.
>
>    ```
>    [magento installation folder]/pub/media/import
>    ```
>
>    You can use a different folder on the Magento server, as long as the path to the folder is specified during the import process.
> 2. In the CSV data, enter the name of each image file to be imported on the correct row, by sku, and in the correct column according to image type (`base_image`, `small_image`, `thumbnail_image`, or `additional_images`).
>
>    > For images in the default import folder(`/pub/media/import`), do not include the path before the filename in the CSV data.
>
>    The CSV file must include only the sku column and the related image columns.
>
>    [image: CSV Import Image from Default Location]
>                                              *CSV Import Image from Default Location*
> 3. Follow the instructions to [import](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import.html) the data.
>
>    After selecting the file to import, enter the relative path following Images File Directory:
>
>    ```
>    /pub/media/import
>    ```
>
>    [image: Images File Directory]
>                                                              *Images File Directory*
>
>    If importing multiple images for a single sku, insert a blank row below the sku, and enter the additional image file names in the appropriate columns. The additional rows are understood to belong to the parent sku.
>
> #### Method 2: Import Images from External Server
>
> 1. Upload the images to be imported to the designated folder on the external server.
> 2. In the CSV data, enter the full URL for each image file in the correct column by image type (`base_image`, `small_image`, `thumbnail_image`, or `additional_images`).
>
>    ```
>    http://example.com/images/image.jpg
>    ```
> 3. Follow the instructions to [import](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import.html) the data.

— http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html

Comment: This answer is much more verbose and helpful. It should definitely be chosen as the correct answer IMO.

Comment: Does anyone know why this doesn't work as described in the docs?
I have posted a question related to this, here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189344/magent-2-1-image-import-documentation-wrong

Comment: Import image from external url will save image name as it is e.g `http://example.com/images/image.jpg` will save image name as: `httpexamplecomimagesimage.jpg` this can't be right?

Answer (score 0):

The following code set main and additional images magento 2

```
if ($mainImage) {
    $image_directory = $mediaPath . DS . 'data' . DS . $mainImage;
    if (file_exists($image_directory)) {
        $product->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()))//media gallery initialization
            ->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false);//assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery
    } 
    else {
        $image_directory = $mediaPath . 'data' . DS . 'comingsoon.jpg';
        $product->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()))//media gallery initialization
            ->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false);
    }
}

// additional images
if ($importProduct[29] != '') {
    $addImages = explode(",", trim($importProduct[29]));
    foreach ($addImages as $additional_image) {
        $image_directory = $mediaPath .DS.'data'.DS. trim($additional_image);
        if (file_exists($image_directory)) {
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, null, false, false);
        } 
        else {
            $image_directory = $mediaPath . 'data' . DS . 'comingsoon.jpg';
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, null, false, false);
        }
    }
    echo 'Additional images for product ' . $product->getName() . ' ' . $product->getId() . ' imported successfully' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Please click here for detailed explanation and absolute media path.
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/code-snippets/import-product-images-magento-2-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is also possible using a third-party solution called Skyvia - their free plan should be enough for your task. Skyvia connects via Magento API and imports product images via CSV as paths to them. Here's the [link](https://skyvia.com/connectors/magento) if you're interested.