# Magento 2.1 Image Import Documentation Wrong

Tags: magento-2.1, import, product-images, csv

I have followed the documented instructions to create the image import CSV, and produced an exact replica of the CSV shown, but with my own product details, obviously.

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html

Then I follow the instructions for the actual import (http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import.html), I choose "Products" entity type, and Import Behaviour "Add/Update", set the image file directory and then choose my CSV file.

When I click check data, it returns an error, saying:

```
1. Product Type is invalid or not supported in row(s): 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.
Checked rows: 13, checked entities: 13, invalid rows: 6, total errors: 6
```

Those rows do not contain a SKU as they are additional images for row 1 SKU, so have been left blank as per the instructions - quoted here:

```
If importing multiple images for a single sku, insert a blank row below the sku, and enter the additional image file names in the appropriate columns. The additional rows are understood to belong to the parent sku.
```

Can someone tell me if the instructions are out of date, and there is a working method to do this? Or if I have to do this some other way?

If it comes to it, I could manually add the additional product images to those products that need them, but would rather the automated method worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem - the data import works fine following the instructions.

The problem was, for some reason my CSV was not comma separated, but semi-colon separated!!

Fix that, and the system works :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to import multiple images for single sku mention multiple image name separated by comma in additional_images column. Do not left blank row.