# How to bulk import products with images into Magento 2 from CSV file

Tags: magento2, csv, product-import

I'm sitting with `Magento 2.3.3`. 
I have a `CSV` file with some products but when I import the products no images are attached.

My imported fine, but when I press Import I get the error message "Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"

I have imported my images into cpanel under `/pub/media/import`. 
(I have also tried placing the images under `var/import`).
[image]

This is the `CSV` file I'm using. 
[image]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W1aQiF15kIUxnIO8FapYcbOtEzS2qtCZogsmcqgkMzQ/edit?usp=sharing

I have been following these instructions but it doesn't seem to work for me.
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html

This didn't either work for me:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/How-to-organise-images-when-importing-cvs-into-my-own-structure/td-p/120238

[How to import product images in bulk into Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101294/how-to-import-product-images-in-bulk-into-magento-2?newreg=5684652ef79944beb28ad3298deb7f7d)

[Magento 2 product import won't import images](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109066/magento-2-product-import-wont-import-images)

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Unable-to-import-images/td-p/24009

https://bsscommerce.com/blog/how-to-import-product-images-in-magento-2/

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem, I've checked folder and file permissions pub/media is set to 777 and memory is set to -1 (no limit), still images aren't being imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading all the images to /var/import/images

Leave the **Images File Directory** blank and import, images should now be imported unless they have image names above 90 characters.